# Does forwarding a link expose my IP address?

Tags: ip, url

So my friend sent me a IP grabbing link. I copied and pasted into playstation messages and sent it to my cousin. I’m wondering if my friend got my IP because I copied and pasted. I didn’t open the link nor click it so am I safe?

Comment: Why would you not be safe? Why do you care if they know your IP?

Comment: Good practice is to access the link without a browser, you'll need to be able to run a command, such as curl or wget on Linux, to download the contents of the link and inspect that contents in a text editor without it being able to execute client side code like javascript. Of course this is but one approach though quick, easy and relatively safe. For extra points run the command over a VPN so as to hide where the request came from.

Answer (score 1):

> I’m wondering if my friend got my IP because I copied and pasted.

No. As I understand it, you relayed a link from your friend to your cousin, without clicking on it. This does not expose your IP address to your friend.

You seem to attach too much security value to your IP address. You expose your IP address all the time to all the sites you visit, so they can send data back to you. If someone has your IP address, this means that they can attempt to connect to your device, but this is not necessarily a security issue.

If you want to burglar a home, it's helpful to know the address of the home you want to rob, but that doesn't mean that house addresses are kept secret. If you want to receive letters, you have no choice but to share your house address.